# what is block dispatch in iOS?

Tags: ios4, objective-c-blocks

Hi I want to understand what is block dispatch?In which condition we can use block dispatch also wanted to know that serial block dispatch and async block dispatch?

Comment: -1 I just Googled 'block dispatch' and any of the first *five* results would have answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and the [Blocks Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html) from Apple. They are very complete and a great resource.

If you're a Registered Apple Developer there are some great videos from WWDC on both topics from 2011 and 2012.